# Elegant way to transform an object to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have a function that returns either an array or a value:

```js
const a = f(...);
// a === [ 1 ];

const b = f(...);
// b = 1;
```

What is the most elegant way to transform the returned value into an array, so that `a === b`?

I was hoping something like `[ ...b ]` would work, but it throws. The solution I have come to so far is `Array.isArray(b) ? b : [ b ]`, but I'm curious if there's a cleaner way to do this, preferably a single function/non-branching expression

Comment: do  u mean the function should always return an array to the outer world (even if the logic returns a value)?

Comment: @SaurabhTiwari It's unfortunately not my function, so I'd like to transform the return value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `Array.prototype.concat` accepts either an array or a single value as a parameter.

*This is assuming you want an array always*.

```js
//This is just to illustrate.
const f = (asArray) => asArray ? [1] : 1,
      a = [].concat(f(true)),
      b = [].concat(f(false));

console.log(a.length === b.length && a[0] === b[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
return [b].flat()
```

Comment: @NickBull you could wrap this into an readable utility function

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a way out is to use the construct

```
Array.from()
```

Example:

```
Array.from(a());
```

and

```
Array.from(b());
```

Both should return you the result in an array.